# How to remove default html mail error message and make zod message instead with react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, zod

this is my schema. using react-hook-form & zod for validation

```
const emailInputSchema = z.object({
  email: z.string().min(1, "input is required").email("email address is not valid"),
});
```

I want to have the message *email address is not valid* instead of the standard HTML email error message:

[image]

I want to have the *input is required* but I don't get this error in the error object.

```
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting },
    reset,
  } = useForm<TEmailInputSchema>({
    resolver: zodResolver(emailInputSchema, { errorMap: customErrorMap }),
  });
```

and here is the form inside of the TSX:

```
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleMailSubmit)}>
        <div className="input-container">
          <div className="input-wrapper rounded">
            <FaRegEnvelope className="input-icon" />
            <input
              type="email"
              {...register("email")}
              placeholder="email"
              className="input"
              autoComplete="email"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        {errors.email && (
          <p className={`${errorStyle}`}>{`${errors.email.message}`}</p>
        )}
        <div className="buttons-container">
          <button
            type="submit"
            disabled={isSubmitting}
            className="form-submit-button"
          >
            Send an email
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ***[`noValidate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#novalidate)*** prop on form element. Something like:

```js
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleMailSubmit)} noValidate>
        <div className="input-container">
          <div className="input-wrapper rounded">
            <FaRegEnvelope className="input-icon" />
            <input
              type="email"
              {...register("email")}
              placeholder="email"
              className="input"
              autoComplete="email"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        {errors.email && (
          <p className={`${errorStyle}`}>{`${errors.email.message}`}</p>
        )}
        <div className="buttons-container">
          <button
            type="submit"
            disabled={isSubmitting}
            className="form-submit-button"
          >
            Send an email
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
```